# AWS EC2 Container Service Scale In Empty Container Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-ecs

Let's suppose that i have an ECS cluster running a service, this service has some autoscaling policies applied to it. When this Service Scales Out, a new task is created, an alarm is then triggered for the AutoScaling group to Launch a new EC2 instance for the Task to Run. I have no troubles on that side.

On the other side, when this service scales In, a task is stoped and deleted. and alarm for Scaling In is triggered for the Autoscaling Group to Terminate an EC2 Instance.

To my knowledge, an AWS Autoscaling Group terminates an EC2 instance (within the group) Randomly in the case of DownScale. Is that so ?

If that's Correct ! is it possible to target only the empty Container Instances to be terminated in the case of DownScale ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's `Random`, I'd say more like `Complex`. See "[Controlling Which Instances Auto Scaling Terminates During Scale In](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html)"

Comment: Based on my current objectif and situation, it's Random after all.

Comment: What information do you get from the scale in alarm. You might need to write something custom, but I bet we can make this work.